# Why does the rendered image in Cycles looks so ugly an not sharp

Tags: rendering, lighting, settings

[image]Hi Guys I wanted to render this beautiful porsch spyder but it doesnt look beautiful on the rendered image. Can someone explain what i can do better or what i did wrong. This one frame took about 2 hours of rendering. is there a faster way to render this?

[image: This Image is showing a porsch spyder in front.]

Here is an example how it should look:

[image: This is the latest Render. Now i Renderd in Eevee. I did not create the Car by myself. Its a Model from Blendswap. Is there any possibility i can improve the car model?]

Blender File: [https://we.tl/t-qlZJyjJ22f[![enter](https://we.tl/t-qlZJyjJ22f%5B!%5Benter) image description here][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA54p.jpg)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA54p.jpg)

Comment: Hello, maybe be more specific, and show a reference picture of what you would like to have as a result? Maybe use an HDRI to have a more interesting lighting and reflection?

Comment: I guess there are 3 aspects that you need to work: model / material / lighting + HDRI. Your model lacks small details, but maybe it doesn't have a lot. The material looks a bit too unreasltic and simple, a tiny bit of dirt and scratch and maybe a bit of clearcoat would improve it. The environment is a bit poor, maybe choose another HDRI, add some lamps (and increase their strength). Also you could post-process a bit with depth of fields, glare effect, etc, it's a good trick to quickly improve an image. Your floor doesn't reflect the car, is it normal?

Comment: @manu000 Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: thanks for all of ur support. I schow u what i have done in a minute

Comment: You better check if the model has custom split normals. Could be the cause. If not, maybe share the blend file so we can check.

Comment: I will but the weTransfer Link in the Description withe the blend File. I changed the material of the car. I also share the new render